# Laravel: Passing default variables to view

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, we all pass data to our view in pretty much the same way

```
$data = array(
    'thundercats' => 'Hoooooooooooh!'
);
return View::make('myawesomeview', $data);
```

But is there some way to add default variables to the view without having to declare it over and over in `$data`? This would be very helpful for repeating variables such as usernames, PHP logic, and even CSS styles if the site demands it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Use View Composers

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a
>   view is created. If you have data that you want bound to a given view
>   each time that view is created throughout your application, a view
>   composer can organize that code into a single location. Therefore,
>   view composers may function like "view models" or "presenters".

**Defining A View Composer :**

```
View::composer('profile', function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

Now each time the profile view is created, the count data will be bound to the view. In your case, it could be for `id` :

```
    View::composer('myawesomeview', function($view)
    {
        $view->with('id', 'someId');
    });
```

So the `$id` will be available to your `myawesomeview` view  each time you create the view using :

```
View::make('myawesomeview', $data);
```

You may also attach a view composer to multiple views at once:

```
View::composer(array('profile','dashboard'), function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

If you would rather use a class based composer, which will provide the benefits of being resolved through the application [IoC Container](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc), you may do so:

```
View::composer('profile', 'ProfileComposer');
```

A view composer class should be defined like so:

```
class ProfileComposer {
    public function compose($view)
    {
        $view->with('count', User::count());
    }
}
```

[Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers) and you can [read this article](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout) too.

Comment: I tested this and it works. But how do I make it apply to *all* views? It seems redundant to have to write it down for every single view. It's fine if you only have a handful, but what if you have around 100+ views?

Comment: Then you have to add that data to the template, you didn't check the link I gave you, [check it here](http://heera.it/laravel-4-view-composer-master-layout).

Comment: Don't have my PHP dev environment setup at work to test, but could you use Route groups with a before filter to include a view composer for all views within the group? Alternatively, instead of binding your individual views, bind the view composer to a master layout? Just thinking out loud here.

Comment: To target all views, I used `'*'` instead of specifying a specific view. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Wow! That's awesome :-)

Comment: `View::make('_myPartial', $data);` to call this from a controller? But how place this somewhere globally and if need I override $data from my controller?

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways, so far I have been experiment with some.

1.Use singleton, you can put it in routes.php

```
App::singleton('blog_tags', function() {
  return array(
    'Drupal'    => 'success',
        'Laravel'   => 'danger',
        'Symfony'   => 'dark',
        'Wordpress' => 'info'
    );
});
```

2.Use Settings bundle, download here. https://github.com/Phil-F/Setting. You can put this in controller or template.

```
Setting::set('title', 'Scheduler | Mathnasium');
```

3.Use View share, pretty much use it in your template

```
Controller: Views::share('theme_path', 'views/admin/');
Template: <link href="{{ $theme_path }}/assets/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

4.My current sample setup, I wrote a construct in HomeController.

```
public function __construct()
{
    // Define a theme namespace folder under public
    View::addLocation('../public/views/admin');
    View::addNamespace('admin', '../public/views/admin');
    View::share('theme_path', 'views/admin/');


    // Set default page title
    Setting::set('title', 'Scheduler | Mathnasium');
    Setting::set('description', 'daily customer scheduler.');
    Setting::set('keywords', ['Reservation', 'Planner']);
    Setting::set('page-title', '');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@enchance, as an alternative to using '*', as mentioned in your comment, perhaps a View::share would help you too.  From the Laravel documentation:

> You may also share a piece of data across all views:
>
> View::share('name', 'Steve');

Excerpt is from http://laravel.com/docs/responses

Answer (score 0):

Yep there absolutely is a way - see here on [view composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers).

You can use that to add data to a view or set of views.