# Laravel: Difference between View::share() and View::composer()

Tags: php, view, laravel

In relation to the question [Passing default variables to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645087/laravel-passing-default-variables-to-view), to pass variables available among all views, is there a technical or functional difference between the use of `View::composer()`:

```
View::composer('*', function($view) {
    $thundercats = 'Woooooohh!!';
    $view->with('thundercats', $thundercats);
})
```

in the *filters.php* file or the use of `View::share()` in the *BaseController.php* file:

```
public function __construct {
    $thundercats = 'Woooooohh!!';
    View::share('thundercats', $thundercats);
}
```

I've only recently learned about `View::share()` and find it exceptionally intruiging although I've already started using the former in another project.

**Edit:**

My first assumption is that the former is a file (*filters.php*) while the the latter is a class (*BaseController.php*). With this in mind, I'm guessing a class is much better? Although, I'm not quite sure why at this point. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Technically they are not at all alike. `View::share` simply sets a variable, while `View::composer` is a callback function.

Let me explain in greater detail:

[`View::share`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/eb35679ce0fe37061d9be6f45821c924d28ba559/src/Illuminate/View/Environment.php#L259-L267) is really straight forward it sets a variable which can be used within any of the views, think of it like a global variable.

[`View::composer`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/eb35679ce0fe37061d9be6f45821c924d28ba559/src/Illuminate/View/Environment.php#L295-L305) registers an event which is called when the view is rendered, don't confuse it with a [`View::creator`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/eb35679ce0fe37061d9be6f45821c924d28ba559/src/Illuminate/View/Environment.php#L276-L286) which is fired when a view is instantiated.

`View::composer` / `View::creator` can both be used as a class which is [well documented](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers).

While these give you the ability to pass additional data to a view, they also give you to ability to do a lot of other things, for example they could:

- Aid in debugging a view
- Log information about views
- Be used to create custom caching (probably not a great idea, but possible)

These are just some examples of what *could* be possible using `View::composer` and `View::creator`.

Comment: I see. So for simplicity's sake, if all you want is to output a 'global' variable then it's better to use `View::share()`. For anything other/more than that, use `View::composer()`.

Comment: For simplicity's sake sure, however if you find yourself defining it over and over again probably abstract it to a `View::composer`.

Comment: Also check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23857517/682754. Both really helped me understand the difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
View::composer('*', callback());
```

Means that the callback will be called for all views (*).

```
View::share
```

Means that a variable will be shared with all outputed views.

Because the first is in filters.php, it'll apply for all routes.

The second is in a controller contructor, so it'll apply for all views triggered by this controller.

One last thing: when overriding a constructor, it's a good pratice to allways call the parent constructor with this code:

```
parent::_construct();
```

Comment: I see. so `Views::composer` variables can be accessible even in _routes.php_ and any other file? Out of curiousity, can this be done to make a specific variable available for all **controllers** other than `$this->varname`?

Comment: If View::composer('*', callback()) is a valid option, it should be in the documentation.