# Laravel 4.2 Pass Variable to master layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

how can I pass variable to specific page in my template

now I have a slider in my banner I need to pass the var `sliders` to `slider.blade` which is under `includes`

**Project map**

```
project
-local
--app
---views
----includes (holds : header, head, footer, **slider**)
```

here is what I tried in Controller

```
protected $layouts = 'includes.slider';

public function index()
{
    $slider = Slider::all();
    $data = array('sliders' => $slider);
    $this->layout->with('slider.sliders', $data);
}
```

and this what I try in the `slider.blade`

```
@if($sliders)
    <h1>TEST</h1>
@endif
```

but I got error

> Undefined variable: sliders

**Edit**

Reviewing the `View Composers` I come out with this

1. Add new folder in my app called `Acme`
2. Add new folder in the `Acme` called `Repositories`
3. declared new class in `Repositories` and called it `HomePageSlider.php`
   here is my new class looks like

   ```
   class HomePageSlider
   {
       public function getAll()
       {
           $getSlider = Slider::all();
           return $getSlider;
       }
   }
   ```
4. now in my home page controller I used it like this `use Acme\Repositories\HomePageSlider;`
5. and then I put the methods and `__construct` like this

   protected $slider;

   ```
   public function __construct(HomePageSlider $slider)
   {
       $this->slider = $slider;
       \View::share('sliders', $this->slider->getAll());
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: are you used this slider for all views?

Comment: @Rimon Khan sorry I didn't get your question

Comment: are use this slider for every page or single page?

Comment: @Rimon Khan no just the first page

Comment: some other vars I will be using for all the pages as drop menu Just need to understand the concept

Comment: OK let me explain this clearly if I call the `sliders` to the page I am viewing now it will work, like I am on `about` page in the `about` controller I will pass this var `sliders` and it will work, but I want to pass this `slider` var in the layouts it self like in the `header.blade` how this can be done?

Comment: in your scenario you should pass the slider var through the `View::Composer()`

Comment: can you please show me an example, how should this be done

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265237/difference-between-view-composer-and-creator-in-laravel-4

Comment: Please upgrade your laravel to 5.2 so that we can be able to help you and it will be easier for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
protected $layouts = 'includes.slider';

public function index()
{
    $slider = Slider::all();
    $data = array('sliders' => $slider);
    $this->layout->with('sliders', $data['sliders']);
}
```

Then you can use variable `$sliders` in your view.

You can also take the use of [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) method, so by using compact method you can do like:

```
public function index()
{
    $sliders = Slider::all();
    return View::make('your_desirde_view_name', compact('sliders'));
    // Or can also do it as (if content is been echoed in layout...)
    // $this->layout->content = View::make('your_desirde_view_name', compact('sliders'));
}
```

Comment: still getting the same error `Undefined variable: sliders`

Comment: but this `slider.blade` is in my layouts it's not a page to `return` to I need to pass the variable to the layouts